# How to make client download xml file from server?

Tags: java, xml, servlets, download, client

My server is implemented with few servlets when each one is responsible for different task.
I need to make client to download a specified xml file from server when a SAVE button in html page pressed.

I've read that the best way is to host file on server and just let client download, but I don't know how to implement it.

Any example will be highly appreciated. :)

p.s.
I'm using JAVA.

Comment: Seriously just type `servlet file download` in the search box and press enter.

Answer (score 0):

Do these steps:

1. Set [proper MIME-type](http://webdesign.about.com/od/multimedia/a/mime-types-by-file-extension.htm) for your file. If you do not want (there's no suitable MIME-type) to set MIME-type specific to your file type, then set it to `application/octet-stream`
2. Set [content length to the response](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html)
3. [Set content disposition](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html)
4. Open output binary stream, then read your file and write its contents to this output stream.

That's it.

Here is [the sample code](http://www.java-forums.org/blogs/servlet/668-how-write-servlet-sends-file-user-download.html)